# How to decrypt password on hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, encryption, hql

I want to decrypt my field on database into a string, and i want to pass it into controller on spring. I have a hibernate class like this:

```
@Id
@Column(name = "USER_ID")

private BigDecimal userId;

@Column(name = "user_name")
private String username;

@Column(name = "EMPLOYEE_ID")
private BigDecimal employeeId;

@Column(name = "encrypted_user_password")
@ColumnTransformer( write="EncryptByPassPhrase('BN1HC1T',?)", read="decrypt ('BN1HC1T',pswd)" )
private String encrypted_user_password;

public BigDecimal getUserId() {
    return userId;
}

public void setUserId(BigDecimal userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public BigDecimal getEmployeeId() {
    return employeeId;
}

public void setEmployeeId(BigDecimal employeeId) {
    this.employeeId = employeeId;
}

public String getEncrypted_user_password() {
    return encrypted_user_password;
}

public void setEncrypted_user_password(String encrypted_user_password) {
    this.encrypted_user_password = encrypted_user_password;
}
```

And the result of query is :

```
select
    karyawan0_.USER_ID as USER_ID1_0_,
    karyawan0_.EMPLOYEE_ID as EMPLOYEE_ID2_0_,
    decrypt('BN1HC1T',
    karyawan0_.encrypted_user_password) as encrypted_user_pas3_0_,
    karyawan0_.user_name as user_name4_0_ 
from
    FND_USER karyawan0_ 
where
    karyawan0_.user_name=?
```

And i get an error like this:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00904: "DECRYPT": invalid identifier
```

My question is right but i get an error. How to fix it?

Comment: Such logic shouldn't be handled on the DB layer in my opinion... Create a service / dao that can take care of decrypting the password programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

The error `ORA-00904` is returned because the object(function `decrypt(?,?)` in this case) does not exist or the DB account does not have proper permissions to access it.